# Problems enabling BITS uploads on Server 2008R2 (eTrust maybe?)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I've been trying to enable BITS uploads in IIS on Server 2008 r2 and I'm getting this as an error messsage:

"An error occurred while enabling BITS uploads. Please check the event log for more details about the exception. Exception Message: External component has thrown an exception"

There is nothing in the logs and googling gives http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/2b79d340-ebeb-49e8-86ca-99b60122d63d as pretty much the only result (which links to the only other result at the bottom of the thread).

On test server a few months back I managed to enable BITS uploads, however now when I create a new directory and try again I get the same error message.

In the meanwhile post a nasty infection my client has installed CA eTrust on their servers so I'm not sure if I'm just fighting the AV software (I have enough rights to disable it temporarily but that doesn't seem to be helping)

Anyone got any thoughts on this? For various reasons I'd rather not use the smb mode on BITS.